# Xcopy does not copy file beofre select F for file or D for directory

Tags: windows, jenkins, xcopy

So I try to copy file via `Xcopy` with this simple `command`:

```
xcopy c:\file.doc d:\file.doc
```

And i received this output:

```
Does C:\file.doc specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

And only after select one of the options the file copied.

Any chance to avoid this message ?
I try to run this via `Jenkins Execute windows batch command` and this not working brabably because this message

Comment: `xcopy c:\file.doc d:\` If you're not changing the filename itself. Otherwise `xcopy c:\file.doc d:\file.doc /F /Y`

Comment: I got the same message

Comment: You get the same message when executing `xcopy c:\file.doc d:`?

Comment: Yes, the same message

Answer (score 0):

Just add `*` char at the end of destination path, in your case:

```
xcopy c:\file.doc d:\file.doc*
```

Also in Windows 11 (not sure about earlier versions) xcopy command has new option `/-I` - if destination does not exist and copying a single specified file, assumes that destination must be a file.